# Is there a reverse \alph?

Tags: counters

Is there a command that does the reverse of `\alph`, i.e. takes a letter and gives me the corresponding number of the letter in the alphabet?

If there is, how about `\Alph`, `\roman` or `\Roman`?

---

Context:

I have a sectioning command `\subtask` for typesetting solutions to exercise sheets where I sometimes don't answer the subtasks in the "correct" order. The subtasks are numbered with small Latin letters using `\alph`.

I adjusted the command so that I can write `\subtask[4]` when I want to jump to the subtask "d". This is fine but `\subtask[d]` would be more user friendly. Hence the question.

Comment: Since `tasks` uses `expl3`, there is `\int_from_alph:n`; can you make a small compilable example of what you have now?

Comment: @egreg: You misunderstood, I am not using the `tasks` package. I defined the sectioning command myself using `scrartcl`'s `\DeclareNewSectionCommand` and adjusted it as described above. I decided not to include a MWE because I was of the opinion that the details of my implementation aren't relevant to the question.
If you still think, an MWE would be helpful, I can add one. However, I think the answers are already perfectly good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The backtick in numerical context can be used to get the character code of a letter. This can be used to calculate the position of the letter in the alphabet.

- The definition range for the argument of `\inversalph` is `a` to `z` and `A` to `Z` for `\inverseAlph`.
- The letter can be hidden inside a macro (or even nested macros).

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\inversalph}[1]{%
  \the\numexpr(\expandafter`\romannumeral-`\x#1-`a+1)\relax
}
\newcommand*{\inversAlph}[1]{%
  \the\numexpr(\expandafter`\romannumeral-`\x#1-`A+1)\relax
}
\begin{document}
  a: \inversalph{a},
  b: \inversalph{b},
  k: \inversalph{k},
  z: \inversalph{z}

  A: \inversAlph{A},
  B: \inversAlph{B},
  K: \inversAlph{K},
  Z: \inversAlph{Z}

  \def\lettera{a}
  \def\letterz{z}
  \def\letteraa{\lettera}
  \def\letterzz{\letterz}
  \lettera: \inversalph{\lettera} = \inversalph{\letteraa},
  \letterz: \inversalph{\letterz} = \inversalph{\letterzz}

   Page: \inversalph{\alph{page}}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- `\numexpr` is used for the calculations.
- `` \romannumeral-`\x `` is a trick to expand the following token multiple
  times.

Answer (score 5):

A quick solution with `\int_from_alph:n` or `\int_from_roman:n` from `expl3`. Note that `a` and `A` does not matter here, as well as uppercase and lowercase roman figures are identical here.

The `\setcounter{section}{\alphtonumber{w}}` example was used to show that the macros are expandable.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\alphtonumber}[1]{%
  \int_from_alph:n{#1}
}


\newcommand{\romantonumber}[1]{%
  \int_from_roman:n{#1}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{pgffor}


\begin{document}


\alphtonumber{a} -- \alphtonumber{z}

And \alphtonumber{M}\ is a pretty number and \romantonumber{MMXVI} is a good year (more or less), as well as \romantonumber{mdcccclxxiv} was a good year. 


\setcounter{section}{\alphtonumber{w}}

\section{Foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The number is always stored in the counter while `\alph` and the like are only for displaying the value.

For example if you define

```
\newcounter{foo}
\renewcommand{\thefoo}{\alph{foo}}
```

with

```
\thefoo
```

you get a, b, c, …

but with

```
\value{foo}
```

you can always access the integer value of the counter.

Comment: Downvoting without explaining why ist really nice …

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but I agree with your anger! (+1)

Comment: I have more and more the impression that the politeness of some TeX.SX users steps down :-(

Comment: @ChristianHupfer thanks for the _empathy up-vote_ :-D

Comment: Not only empathy. I would have upvoted immediately after posting my solution, but I didn't catch you have answered too!